# What are the main differences between a register-base VM vs a stack-based one?

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik

Today I was reading [some slides about Andoird basics](http://www.slideshare.net/mdesjardins/android-development-the-basics) and the phrase appeared:

> Dalvik VM is register based instead of stack based.

So, **What are the main differences between a register-base VM vs a stack-based one?**

---

The second link answerd enough my question:

http://markfaction.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/stack-based-vs-register-based-virtual-machine-architecture-and-the-dalvik-vm/

Another link:

http://androidjayavelu.blogspot.co.at/2011/06/dalvik-virtual-machine-vs-java-virtual.html

Comment: From the Java source level there is no conceptual difference.  The difference is in the bytecodes (that javac produces), where the stack-based bytecodes are written in terms of a stack, while (surprise!) for the register-based model the bytecodes are written in terms of registers.

Comment: (JIT-compiled Java, even on a "stack-based" architecture, is register-based.)

Comment: this link will help you to getting more explanation http://markfaction.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/stack-based-vs-register-based-virtual-machine-architecture-and-the-dalvik-vm/

Comment: This is what I would just write as an answer based on machine language programing.  register based programs have physical limits for instance a deck of cards is 52 a physical limit.  Stack based programs are only limited by the amount of memory and use lists or push onto the stack as much data as is needed and pop off the stack.  So the new stack based version would have less constraints on the amount of memory or number of apps that can be running simultaneously.  Perhaps even a pagefile to access the memory on the sd cards.